# Find number of common words in SQL table columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an SQL table with two text columns and I'd like find the number of words in each of those and also the number of common words.

Basically a word should be the regex `[A-Za-z]{3,}` (at least 3 chars) and for a row with the values `left="abc def ghi"` and `right="ghi abc qwe rtz"` the result should be `wordsleft=3`, `wordsright=4`, `wordscommon=2` (since they share `abc` and `ghi`).

Can I do that with SQL only?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: SQL is really not the right way to do this.  You basically need to parse all the words out into a separate table (or CTE) and then do a complicated join.

Comment: I believe it's Oracle.

Comment: SQL is an excellent way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, even though SQL might not be the best option to do something like this (it's probably a lot easier using a scripting language) you can do it using common table expressions with `connect by` queries to split the strings into rows and then count the number of distinct items in each column (and the common items).

Given a table like this:

```
| ID |            L |               R |
|----|--------------|-----------------|
|  1 |  abc def ghi | ghi abc qwe rtz |
|  2 |     bc de gh |  gh ab qw rt xx |
|  3 | xbc de gh yy |          gh xbc |
```

You can get this result:

```
| ID | COMMON_COUNT | LEFT_COUNT | RIGHT_COUNT |
|----|--------------|------------|-------------|
|  1 |            2 |          3 |           4 |
|  2 |            1 |          3 |           5 |
|  3 |            2 |          4 |           2 |
```

Using this query (which I'm sure can be optimized and improved - Oracle isn't my thing really):

```
with 
cte_left as (
  SELECT DISTINCT ID, regexp_substr(l, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL) l
  FROM t
  CONNECT BY regexp_substr(l, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY ID
),
cte_right as (
  SELECT DISTINCT ID, regexp_substr(r, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL) r
  FROM t
  CONNECT BY regexp_substr(r, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY ID
),
cte_all as (
  select cte_left.id, cte_left.l, cte_right.r 
  from cte_left
  join cte_right on cte_left.id = cte_right.id
)

select id, count(distinct l) as common_count,
    (select count(distinct l) from cte_all where id = t.id) as left_count,
    (select count(distinct r) from cte_all where id = t.id) as right_count
from cte_all t
where l in (select r from cte_all)
group by t.id;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73b13/7)

Comment: your solution doesn't take into account the OP's requirement that words be 3 or more alphabetic characters long.  Two character strings and strings containing numerals or other non alpha characters shouldn't count.

Comment: your extra `select r from cte_all` in your where clause is unnecessary, since cte_all already has all combinations of `l` and `r` values, you can use this more efficient predicate `where l = r`

Comment: @Sentinel Good point about the `where` clause, you're absolutely right. As for the requirement that the words should be 3 alpha chars I assumed that the OP could adjust that part according to his requirements - that's not really the difficult part - the string splitting is in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

SQL is an excellent tool for this.  Using jpw's dataset and the OP's requirement that words be 3+ characters in length:

```
with t1(id, l, r) as (
  select 1, 'abc def ghi', 'ghi abc qwe rtz' from dual union all
  select 2, 'bc de gh', 'gh ab qw rt xx' from dual union all
  select 3, 'xbc de gh yy', 'gh xbc' from dual
), t2(id, words, word, idx, cnt) as (
  select id
       , l
       , regexp_substr(l, '[[:alpha:]]{3,}', 1, 1)
       , 1
       , regexp_count(l,'[[:alpha:]]{3,}')
    from t1
  union all
  select id, words, regexp_substr(words, '[[:alpha:]]{3,}', 1, idx+1)
       , idx+1, cnt
    from t2
  where idx < cnt
), t3(id, words, word, idx, cnt) as (
  select id
       , r
       , regexp_substr(r, '[[:alpha:]]{3,}', 1, 1)
       , 1
       , regexp_count(r,'[[:alpha:]]{3,}')
    from t1
  union all
  select id, words, regexp_substr(words, '[[:alpha:]]{3,}', 1, idx+1)
       , idx+1, cnt
    from t3
  where idx < cnt
)
select coalesce(t2.id,t3.id) id
     , count(t2.word) left_cnt
     , count(t3.word) right_cnt
     , count(case when t2.word = t3.word then 1 end) common_cnt
  from t2
  full join t3
    on t3.id = t2.id
   and t3.word = t2.word
 group by coalesce(t2.id,t3.id);

        ID   LEFT_CNT  RIGHT_CNT COMMON_CNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          3          4          2
         2          0          0          0
         3          1          1          1
```

Comment: Note that the regex used here will look for substrings of at least 3 characters - `SELECT 4, '123abc456', 'kdi ddw 789abc123' FROM DUAL` would show a match on `abc`.  If this isn't desired, change the regex to an appropriate variant of `(^|\W)[[:alpha:]]{3,}` (word has to start with a character), then TRIM the REGEXP_SUBSTR calls (to get rid of any leading/rtailing spaces).

Answer (score 0):

As they mentioned in the commennts, SQL is not the best tool for this. What you can do is to define 2 functions to return common words, words unique for right and left side. Then you can run a query like

```
      select common_words(column_right, column_left), 
             unique_words(column_right, column_left), 
             unique_words(column_left,column_right) 
    from table
```